# Popup with parent window notification

Tags: javascript, dom-events, popupwindow

I have a web app which opens a new popup window with JavaScript and after the user authenticate inside the popup window I want to close it (which I do with `window.close()`) and reload the window which opened the popup window. How could I do that?

JS-Popup-Code:

```
var w = window.open("url", "title", "width=990,height=500,resizable=yes");
w.focus();
```

Comment: Stop writing tags in titles, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
opener.refresh()
```

before you close your window.

Comment: Firefox 5 says that `opener.refresh()` isn't a (known) function. I searched then for a solution, this worked for me: `opener.location.reload(); window.close();`